# C/Python API : efficiency of Py_BuildValue use

Tags: python, c

I'm currently using the C/Python API to read data from a large binary file.
This result in Python is not as efficient as the pure C result (time x2) because, I think, of the time took to wrap things up into a PyObject. Typically, I store 42-elements tuples in a PyArrayObject. To do this, I use:

`PyObject *r = Py_BuildValue("(f, I, i, K, f, K, K, etc..)", a, b, c, etc...) ;`

My question is the following: Is there a more efficient way to do it (quicker execution time)?

For example: will PyTuple_Pack(n, args) do it more quickly ?

Comment: Yes, write your program in C.

Answer (score 0):

For time critical code, I create a tuple of the desired length and then create the components individually and stuff them into the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are writing your own customised `struct.unpack` ... did you try writing your binary file reader in pure Python (a very quick job) to use as a "strawman"?

```
import struct
fmt = "f I i Q f Q Q etc.." # check endianness and alignment
structobj = struct.Struct(fmt)
recsz = structobj.size
assert recsz == EXPECTED_RECSZ
unpack = structobj.unpack
f = open('bigfile.bin', 'rb')
while True:
    record = f.read(recsz)
    if not record: break
    a_tuple = unpack(record)
    do_something(a_tuple)
f.close()
```

Asides: (1) File has 32-bit floats and 64-bit integers? (2) Py_BuildValue with parens in the 1st arg returns a tuple; what is this "PyArrayObject" you mentioned?

Comment: I've tried it in Python with struct.unpack but it's just too slow. 1: file has many kinds of numbers type : uint32, uint16, int32, etc... 2: the PyArray is the array I store my uples into. I think I'll stay with the Py_BuildValue solution, even if it's a bit slow. Thanks for yous replys.

Comment: (1) My code example doesn't call `struct.unpack`; it precompiles the format. How large are your files? How long does it take to load an average file? (2) the point about data types was that I thought it rather unusual for a file to have both 32-bit floats and 64-bit integers

Comment: Ok. I did not understand that the first time. I'll try your idea on Monday, it's seems indeed better. My file take ~20sec to load for a 20Mo

Comment: Sorry...: Ok. I did not understand that the first time. I'll try your idea (on Monday)  of the precompiled format, it seems better indeed, and can prevent me from using C. My file take ~20sec to be read (20Mo). (2): there are just integers, but some of them I transform into floats for physical meaning purpose. I'll keep you informed. Thks.

Comment: You are transforming (small) C integers into C `float` (32-bit floating point format), and then passing that to Py_BuildValue for it to transform them to Python `float` (64-bit floating point format) ???

Comment: Yes, and I realise I should have used C double. I've tried the Struct class solution, but strangely it is not quicker than using strut.unpack (and recompile the format each time)..